# How to put two Bearer keys in Postman?

Tags: postman, mercure

My `Symfony` project uses an authentication check; so there is a `token` involved. Now I use `Mercure` as a real-time mechanism used in Symfony; it uses a `JWT` token also. So how can I put the two Bearer tokens in Postman in order to test my Symfony API ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting bearer token from auth, go to params and add respective tokens. You can also set variables for them.
Just make sure that these two tokens have different key names.

Comment: Is it possible if I set just one Bearer token and add the other token in the params ?

Comment: these tokens will have to be in separate keys. Else, later one with over ride the previous value. So make the change on server to accept the other token on some other key.